# How to understand the meaning of char *fptr = NULL, *field;?

Tags: c, pointers, ansi-c

I would like to know what the following expression means:

```
char *fptr = NULL, *field;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the code found inside a function or outside?  The difference matters because if it is inside, then `field` is uninitialized and can only be used safely as the target of an assignment (or passed by pointer) before it is initialized.  If it is outside a function, then `field` is implicitly initialized -- also to null.

Comment: It's equivalent to `char *fptr = NULL; char *field;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `char` pointer `fptr` and initialize it to `NULL` and declare another `char` pointer `field`. The `NULL` is `((void *)0)` just an invalid pointer value and you can use it to verify if the pointer is valid.

Assigning `NULL` to a pointer helps you avoid dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, for example `malloc` returns `NULL` on failure.

That way if you check your pointer against `NULL` after a call to `malloc`, you prevent undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't think of `NULL` as an address, but as a sentinel value. Especially as it might not actually *be* address 0.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I got it now, I kept looking at it and wouldn't realize that this is two declarations. Thanks again!

Comment: @user145190 read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for more information on the comma operator.